# Matlab Double For Loop

Tags: matlab

Beginner at Matlab. Let's say I have a matrix

```
A = [ 2,3,4;
      6,9,1;
      7,8,3;
      2,2,2 ]
```

I want to manipulate each column into a new column (of potentially different size) and then I want to have the whole new matrix. As an example, suppose I want to get rid of every number less than 4 and raise every other number to the fourth power. This is much simpler than what I'm actually trying to do so don't read too much into those specifics.

If I were to do it for a specific column, say the first one, I would do

```
newcolumn=[];
for r=1:4
    if A(r,1)<4
        newcolumn=newcolumn
    else
        newcolumn=vertcat(newcolumn,(A(r,1))^4))
    end
end
```

Is it possible to do a double for loop to create the whole matrix?

Thanks

Comment: What should happen if the number of elements less than 4 in each column are unequal? I hope you realize that we cannot just remove it since the number of elements in each row should be equal and same applies for column, if you want it to be a matrix. In your example, if I remove elements less than 4, then A will be a vector=`[6 7 9 8 4]`. Now how to arrange it in a new matrix?

Answer (score 1):

So if you want the columns to no longer be of the same size then you will have to use a cell array or pad you numerical matrix with some defualt value, probably `NaN`. Also you don't need a double loop because your loop above is unecessary:

```
newcolumn=[];
for r=1:4
    if A(r,1)<4
        newcolumn=newcolumn
    else
        newcolumn=vertcat(newcolumn,(A(r,1))^4))
    end
end
```

is equivalent to

```
newcolumn = A(A(:,1) < 4, 1).^4;
```

so now you just need to loop along the columns:

```
jaggedArray{1,size(A,2)} = []; %// Pre-allocate your array (NB for efficiency in Matlab!)
for col = 1:size(A,2)
    jaggedArray{col} = A(A(:,col) < 4, col).^4;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If the result has a different number of elements for each row, you can use a [cell array](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) to store it.

Two possible approaches:

1. Using **[`arrayfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html)** (which is equivalent to a `for` loop):

   ```
   B = arrayfun(@(n) A(n,A(n,:)>=4).^4, 1:size(A,1), 'uniformoutput', false);
   ```

   This takes every number `n` from `1` up to the number of rows `size(A,1)`, and applies to it the [anonymous function](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) `@(n) A(n,A(n,:)>=4).^4`,  which does what you want. It then puts the result into `B{n}`. The option `'uniformoutput', false` indicates that the results are not scalars, so a cell array is created to store them.
2. Using **[`cellfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html)**: If the function you want to apply to each row is complicated, instead of using an anonymous function you may define it normally in a file, say `foo.m`. In this case it's easier if your function accepts a row (not the number `n`) as input:

   ```
   %// File foo.m
   function y = foo(x) %// x is a row, y is a row of possibly different size
   y = x(x>=4).^4;
   ```

   You then split `A` into a cell array of its rows

   ```
   Acell = mat2cell(A, ones(1,size(A,1)), size(A,2));
   ```

   and then call `cellfun` with a [function handle](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-handles.html) to your function:

   ```
   B = cellfun(@foo, Acell, 'uniformoutput', false);
   ```

I know all this may be a little beyond Matlab beginner's knowledge, but that's the point of the answer :-)